# Secure redirect from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, http, ssl, https, header

I once read an article somewhere, and I can't find it now (don't you hate that!!!!) that documented a way of securely requesting an elevation to HTTPS server side. I remember it saying that it fixed some issues with man-in-the-middle attacks stopping the elevation under normal redirect methods. I'm pretty sure I remember them using a HTTP Header but just cannot remember what it was or how they did it. Has anyone heard of what I'm talking about or where I may find this article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header you're looking for is `Strict-Transport-Security`. Read about them over at [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Syntax:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=expireTime [; includeSubdomains]
```

Of course, this header will only work when you're already on a HTTPS connection, so you still have to do the initial redirect.

Comment: On another note, is there a way to detect a browsers support for HTTPS then use a Location redirect and then send that Header? I want to sort of "softly" force HTTPS on our users. I don't want to have a URL Rewrite as some people just don't care about SSL and either disable it or have a really really really old browser.

Comment: You could probably use a `<script src="https://<site>/redirect.js">` javascript redirect. Might even work with javascript disabled, because of the header that'll get set.